# How do I find time continuous A, B matrices from a discrete state space model?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

The easiest way to compute a discrete state space model from time continuous state space model is by this method.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_d & B_d \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix} = \exp\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} h\right),
$$

But how would it be if I have the discrete state space model and I want to find the time continuous state space model?

Edit: I'm just guessing now. Is this the right method?

$$\frac {1}{h}\ln \left(\begin{bmatrix}
A_d & B_d \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, except that the matrix logarithm is not the elementwise logarithm, and in fact is not even single-valued. This also assumes that the coefficient matrix for the continuous process is constant; if it isn't then this statement only makes sense for $h \to 0$. It may help to recall the "formal" version of Taylor's theorem: $e^{hD}=I+\Delta_h$, where $D$ is the differentiation operator, $I$ is the identity operator, and $(\Delta_h f)(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$.

Comment: So how can I compute that? I have tried to compute discrete to continuous and I ger conplex number. Some negative too.

Comment: Can you diagonalize your coefficient matrix? If so then you can use the logarithm elementwise on the diagonal elements.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with diagonalize my coefficients. Do you mean Jordan form?

Comment: You mean turn $A_d $ to a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I mean the whole matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A_d & B_d \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$. If you can diagonalize the whole thing then it is feasible to get the matrix logarithm analytically. I think it can also be done for the Jordan form case but that's going to be more difficult.

Comment: Is there any matlab command for that ? [D, T] = Eig(X) ?

Comment: Sure, though that's not quite the right syntax.

Comment: Sorry. Did not work.

Comment: How exactly? It's likely that you did something silly, like just applying log() straight up and winding up trying to take log(0).

Comment: First I did [D, T] = eig (M) and M is the large matrix. Then i realize that D and T got complex values. I have been used log ().

Comment: The complex numbers are no real surprise...but you still can't just take log(T), you have to take the elementwise logarithm along the diagonal, i.e. diag(log(diag(T))).

Comment: I did diag(log(diag(T))) and then I going to take log again ?

Comment: No...the matrix logarithm of M is D*diag(log(diag(T)))*inv(D). That can also be achieved by the Matlab function logm.

Comment: Now it is working. I use log(M)*1/h to get the continuous matrecies. Thank you. Logm really solved this problem. Why don't you write the answer the question so I can accept it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find $T=\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ such that $\exp(hT)=\begin{bmatrix} A_d & B_d \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}=:M$, then you can compute $\log(M)/h$ where $\log$ is the matrix logarithm. The matrix logarithm, like the complex logarithm, is multi-valued, but the principal one can be obtained by the Matlab function logm.

Comment: Logm(M)/h  . Not log (M)/h.  :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson In math notation we still write it that way, even though you need different notation in programming.